# Powershell commands only work when I run selection in ise

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm new to powershell and I'm using the ps ise to write a ps script that executes a .exe remotely on another server.

When I click run in the ise, the script doesn't appear to do anything. However, when I right-click on the individual lines of code in the ps script, I can see within the ps console and the target server that each line of code works.

What am I missing to get it to work when I just click run script in the ise or when I run the script from the command line?

Here is what the script basically looks like:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MyServer1
D:\Somefolder\On\TargetServer\theremote.exe
Exit-PSSession
```

I appreciate any help or guidance on this.

Answer (score 3):

Let me explain you.

**Enter-PSsession** basically creates an interactive session with the remote computer.

So once the session has been created, you can run all the commands which interactive will return the result from the remote computer.

You should use `invoke-command` to get your job done . It should be like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyServer1 -ScriptBlock {& 'D:\Somefolder\On\TargetServer\theremote.exe'}
```

Now, by default it uses Windows Authentication. If you want to specify any credentials then you can use `-Credential` switch.

Or another method is to create a remote session first using `new-pssession`, then store the session in a variable. 
Finally, you can specify the session in the invoke-command as `-SessionName`

As per the comments, this is **how you can pass the parameters**(I am passing only 1 parameter here):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName MyServer1 -ScriptBlock { param ($param1) & 'D:\Somefolder\On\TargetServer\theremote.exe' -something $param1 } -ArgumentList "param1Value"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try. I also have to send parameters to the exe on the other server. How would I do that using your code?

Comment: For parameters you can use argumentlist switch in the invoke-command and , you can access it inside the scriptblock as param. If u want i can edit the answer with parameters

Comment: Yes, can you please edit the answer to show how parameters can used?

Comment: @tmontez36: I have added in the answer how to pass the parameter also. Hope it help you to understand in a better way now.